# Spring MVC with H2 throwing table not found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, h2

I know that this kind of a question happened to occur many times, but I'm still missing something. I'm building some simple web shop application with a classic Spring MVC (not Boot!), JPA with Hibernate and unfortunate H2 :)

This is my `application.properties`:

```
################### DataSource Configuration ##########################
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:webshop;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.username=webshopdba
spring.datasource.password=123
spring.datasource.initialize=true
################### JPA ###################
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
################### H2 ###################
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
################### Hibernate ###################
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=INFO
hibernate.show-sql=true
```

Here's an example model class:

```
package com.webshop.model;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "PROGRAM")
public class Program {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "PROGRAM_NAME")
    private String programName;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;
}
```

And here's persistence config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.webshop.repositories")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.webshop.repositories")
public class PersistenceConfig {

    private final Environment env;

    @Autowired
    public PersistenceConfig(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .setName("webshop")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show-sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show-sql"));
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect"));
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.webshop");
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer() {
        ResourceDatabasePopulator resourceDatabasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        resourceDatabasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("/schema-h2.sql"));

        DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
        dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(dataSource());
        dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(resourceDatabasePopulator);
        return dataSourceInitializer;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

And here's `schema-h2.sql`:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS webshop;

SET SCHEMA webshop;

CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS WEBSHOPDBA PASSWORD '123' ADMIN;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PROGRAM
(
    ID                  BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PROGRAM_NAME        VARCHAR(255),
    DESCRIPTION         VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO PROGRAM
(PROGRAM_NAME, DESCRIPTION)
VALUES ('Example software', 'Example')
```

Right now the application boots up properly, reads schema-h2.sql, loads it and it's ready for work, but if I do anything related to the persistence, it throws

```
SqlExceptionHelper:142 - Table "PROGRAM" not found; SQL statement:
insert into PROGRAM (PROGRAM_NAME, DESCRIPTION) values (null, ?, ?) [42102-196]
```

Although I can use `/h2-console` path and get into H2, where my schema, table and one example insert are present (with a user defined in SQL). I can also see in tomcat logs that my queries where executed successfully. What might be the issue here? I feel like when trying to perform any persistence action my code creates a new instance of the DB and the previous one is lost, however `DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1` should prevent that according to the H2 docs.

What I've tried so far:

- Setting hibernate ddl-auto or hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to create/create-drop/update/none - no difference,
  `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create`
- Dividing my SQL file into schema/data, import, just schema, no difference as well,
- Explicitly declare `spring.datasource.initialization-mode=embedded` with no effect,
- Adding init schema to connection string,
- Declaring dataSource with DriverManagerDataSource

I'm slowly running out of ideas, can someone advice me what I might be doing wrong here? Help me StackOverflow you are my only hope!

Comment: i think that create statement is sintactically incorrect, try removing "," in "DESCRIPTION         VARCHAR(255),"

Comment: Thanks for the response, that's true although that was mistake in my copy paste :) It isn't  there in the actual code, I've updated the snippet

Comment: You don't need to mention NOT NULL while setting primary key, so you can create table such as ;

     ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,

Comment: That's a fair note, thanks I'll apply that change. Still the query itself manages to created table properly, at least that's what I'm seeing in /h2-console, I'll definitely focus more on code cleanup and optimization once I i'll hit working database.

Comment: Just to make things clear, I've did a check by manually logging into h2 using console - (jdbc:h2:mem:webshop;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1) and my schema + insert query works fine, the problem lies somewhere else, I belive in connection, as I suspect it creates new (?) one rather than using what it have